# Irrlicht GUI Editor import file

Tags: c++, user-interface, irrlicht

I am currently developing a software which uses irrlicht library.

I want to use the GUIEditor to design menus, but I am not able to import the file that the GUIEditor exported in my project.

Here is the way I proceeded :

```
gui->loadGUI("xml_file");
```

But it doesn't seem to work. My menus are not shown in my view.

Have you any solution ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI editor currently lacks a decent menu editor, this is my fault; I didn't get around to writing one.

Support for a menu editor is included though, if you add a GUI factory that adds `menu_editor` and `contextmenu_editor` widgets then the GUI editor should automatically use them to display the menus, but until they're written you'll have to actually create your menus in code then use `saveGUI` to write them out as XML.